# for all prime $p$, how to prove $a = (p!-1)$ is the only integer $a$ that satisfy $p! | (a^p + 1)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

suppose $1 \leq a \leq p!$.

It's easy to prove when $a=p!-1$, that $p!$ divides $(a^p + 1)=((p!-1)^p+1)$.

But how do we prove the uniqueness for such an $a$? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Huh?  $p!-1$ is never going to be between $1$ and $p$ when $p\geq 3$.

Comment: sorry, just corrected the typo error.